# Append a specific object (but same type) to a filtered object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

If I get a list of `User` objects like this

```
special_user_list = User.objects.filter( userprofile__user_type = 'special' )
```

how do I also append `request.user` (the current logged in user), which is also a `User`?

I know I can probably do something like

```
special_user_list = User.objects.filter(
    Q( userprofile__user_type = 'special' ) |
    Q( pk = request.user.pk )
)
```

but I'm not sure the above code may double-include `request.user` (if `request.user.get_profile().user_type = 'special'` as well). Also I want to avoid hitting the database with a complicated SQL statement for adding a user, whom I already know the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's cheaper for the database to do it than for Python to do it.

```
special_user_list = User.objects.filter(
    Q(userprofile__user_type='special') |
    Q(pk=request.user.pk)
).distinct()
```

Comment: Really? Is a filtered queryset not just a list? I can't use Python's `append()`?

Comment: No. A filtered `QuerySet` is still a `QuerySet`. Its representation just *looks* like a list.

Comment: Ignacio, I' guess @hobbes3 don't need to do `.distinct()` here, because there is only one left outer join

Comment: Probably not. But my sentence stands.